# Nodemailer fails on live server but works on local machine

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Using nodemailer to send a registration confirmation email. Works fine on my local machine, but fails from live server (using DigitalOcean droplet & InMotionHosting email account).

I have tried as many things as I can think of to no avail, so I don't know what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
           host: 'mail.domain.com',
           port: 587,
           secure: false, 
           auth: {
              user: 'test@domain.com',
              pass: '654cba'     
           },
           // true for live server, false for local machine
           tls: {
              rejectUnauthorized: true
           }
        });


        let mailOptions = {
           from: '"Register" <test@domain.com>', 
           to: user.username,  // email address from user object 
           subject: 'Registration',
           html: '<h1>mail content</h1>'
        };


        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
           if (error) {

              console.log(error);

              return res.send('Error sending confirmation email to: ' + user.username);
           }

           console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);


           req.flash('success', 'Success! Welcome ' + user.fullname + '! Please check your email, and click the link to complete your registration.');

           res.redirect('/');
        });
```

I set the `tls.rejectUnauthorized` to 'false' for the local machine and it works as expected.

On the live server, I set it to 'true', but receive the error message ('Error sending confirmation email to: ' + user.username) after transporter.sendMail() is executed. I tried eliminating this among many other tests to no avail.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: What is the error that gets printed in your log?

Comment: I am not getting error messages in my console logged into the droplet like I do on my local machine. Using pm2. I have not tackled how to fix that yet.

Comment: I discovered the error. In the `from` property of  mailOptions I was passing the email address like this: `"Jim" ${config.mail.testAccount}`, instead of like this: `"Jim" <${config.mail.testAccount}>`.  I omitted the gt & lt brackets wrapping the email address.

Comment: So it's working now?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read my post. Yes, it works. But I also have the value of `tls.rejectUnauthorized` set to `false` (false is supposed to be the local machine setting per a tutorial). I haven't tested to see if it works set to `true`, but I will do that next.

Comment: Set to `true` it failed quickly. Reset to `false` it works.

Comment: Here's more from nodemailer about the `tls.rejectUnauthorized` code: [link](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/). They say it "Allows self-signed certificates. This config would open a connection to TLS server with self-signed or invalid TLS certificate"

Comment: rejectUnauthorized
If not false the server will reject any connection which is not authorized with the list of supplied CAs This is what that flag does according to this documentation 
https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_tlssocket

So I believe you'll have add certificate

Comment: During production I was having similar errors across multiple domains (gmail, outlook). I would recommend Mailgun or SenGrid, as suggested by this article: https://community.nodemailer.com/using-gmail/ WIth Mailgun, I was up and running within 15 minutes in production.